# Не работает спящий режим в windows 8

Tags: windows-8

На компьютере стоит windows 8 и windows 7 на разных томах. При переходе в спящий режим на виндоус 7, компьютер выключается, а windows 8 нет. Монитор отключается, а компьютер (стационарный ПК) не выключается(шумит, винты крутит, жёсткий слышно).Как это исправить? Переустановка windows 8 не помогла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимо, это т.н. "гибридный спящий режим", который сочетает в себе как "спящий режим", так и "гибернацию" (применяется обычно для стационарных компов). А в режим "гибернации" Винды не могут уйти, если они не на загрузочном разделе стоят (и даже если не на первом, кроме скрытых). Вплоть до семёрки - это точно, а восьмёрку я ещё не пытал пока. Ну, похоже, и там тоже!

То есть, на восьмёрке, если она вторая и на другом разделе, это не вылечится. Как вариант - искать загрузчик с попеременным скрытием и переназначением загрузочных разделов. Вроде бы, Acronis это умел, но точно не помню.